# Script crashes when trying to read a specific Japanese character from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, cjk

I was trying to save some Japanese characters from a text file into a string. Most of the characters like "道" make no problems. But others like "坂" don't work. When I'm trying to read them, my script crashes.
Do I have to use a specific encoding while reading the file?

That's my code btw:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
```

The error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 310: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message when the script crashes?

Comment: Hi LiQ, please include an example of the file and extensive error message so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: The error message is: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 310: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Yes you should open the file with a specific encoding.

Comment: Which encoding should i use?

Comment: @LiQ *how are we supposed to know the encoding of your text file*?

Comment: But try the common ones, `"utf-8"` is generally a good guess

Comment: utf-8 supports all of the CJK characters

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) are the docs for the standard encodings supported by Python. Looks like for Japanese characters, `"cp932"` might be another good guess

Comment: @IgnaceVau well, the issue isn't really what utf-8 *supports*, it's what the files is actually encoded in

Comment: Thats my file: https://workupload.com/file/6EEHCYqKKPa

Comment: @LiQ yeah, in general, it is up to whoever provides a text file to provide the encoding. Any given set of characters could be encoded in more than one way, so just because it is a set of characters doesn't mean you can know the encoding. And you cannot tell the encoding just by looking at a file, although, there are tools that use heuristics to give you good guesses. And, well, you can always try guessing yourself. Unfortunately, we do not live in a world where unicode is the standard, although slowly we might get there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the encoding when working with non ASCII, like this:

```
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: "*You have to specify the encoding when working with non ASCII*": I'd reformulate this assertion more precisely, considering [`open()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#open): *In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform-dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.*